# Getting TRACE-level logging out of WebSphere via slf4j

Tags: logging, websphere, slf4j, java.util.logging

I've written a Servlet Filter and have deployed it as part of a web application on WebSphere 8.5. The filter uses slf4j as its logging facade, and includes the slf4j-to-JUL bridge to pipe log messages to JUL, which is what WebSphere uses.

We have enabled WebSphere tracing, and configured the log detail levels to "all" for our package. The server creates SystemOut.log and trace.log. What I observe is that the "info" level messages appear in SystemOut.log, and the "debug" level messages appear in trace.log. However, I cannot figure out how to get the "trace" level messages to appear anywhere.

In the WAS console, under *Logging and tracing-->server1-->Change log detail levels*, I've specified the following to get ALL messages from our package:

```
*=info: com.idfconnect.*=all
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?